# Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s):

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a username based on first and last name. I want just the first initial of the username. When I try the code below I get this error

[image: Substring]

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\Alex.piwowar.adm.j2global\desktop\ExcelMicroADAdd.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    $First=$_."First"
    $Last=$_."Last"
    $Location=$_."Location"
    $Title=$_."Title"
    $Department=$_."Department"
    $ManagerName=$_."Manager"
    $Company=$_."Company"

    $FirstIntitial = $First.Substring(0,1)
}
```

From my understanding what I entered will start at the beginning of `$First` and move over one which should be the first letter.

Am I thinking incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You assertion of how your code is *supposed to work* is correct. My assumption here is that `$first` is a zero-length string. I can get this error from doing the following:

```
"".Substring(0,1)
```

The error is stating that the string is not long enough to return one characters. Zero-length would explain that.

Have a look at your source data possibly or debug `$first`/`$_.First` at the time of failure. Also you don't need to use quotes on single word properties. Just ones with special characters or spaces.

Once you get that issue figured out....If you only wanted the first character though you can treat string like a character array to just return the first character. I do so when making my new account scripts

```
$FirstIntitial = $First[0]
```

Comment: that seemed to work. How can i go about changing $FiristIntial to uppercase?

Comment: @user71317  `$First[0].ToUpper()`

Comment: I get error - Method invocation failed because [System.Char] doesnt contain a method named ToUpper

Comment: @user71317 oops sorry about that. `([string]$First[0]).ToUpper()` or `$First.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()` should work to.